# How to modify this HTML and JavaScript so it give multiple movable items on the Web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I found this code on-line which creates a screen-draggable "card".

I would like to add more cards. I tried simply making more 's of the card, but that left me with cards that didn't move at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <style>
body {
  background-image: url('background1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style> 


<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Fun</h1>

<p>Click to move the card around</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>


<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I add more than just one card that is movable to this?

Answer (score 1):

For every card you would have to replicate the script and put 2 or 3 or 4 after the function ex: `myFunction2` ect.

I used your same example but made a new replicate of your script and put 2 in the function here is the final script I got and works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <style>
body {
  background-image: url('background1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style> 


<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Fun</h1>

<p>Click to move the card around</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <div id="mydivheader2">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>
<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

function dragElement2(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown2;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown2;
  }

  function dragMouseDown2(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement2;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag2;
  }

  function elementDrag2(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement2() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Lemme know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with just copying the html, is that you need to copy the css and javascript as well. And on top of that you need to change the id's of the new elements, because otherwise all will be a mess.

This example will not teach you nice code, but to answer your question:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fun</h1>

<p>Click to move the card around</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
  <div id="mydivheader2">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>
```

But you could better use a script based on classes. This will give you less redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

First, change the CSS so that you are using general classes, rather than IDs:

```
 .my-div-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.div-header {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then, apply these classes to your two (or whatever) cards, along with the appropriate ID (`#mydivtwo etc), as per the script:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="my-div-wrapper">
    <div id="mydivheader" class="div-header">Click here</div>
    <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>

<div id="mydivtwo" class="my-div-wrapper">
    <div id="mydivtwoheader" class="div-header">Click here</div>
    <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>
```

Then, just call the relevant function on the relevant elements:

```
  dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
  dragElement(document.getElementById("mydivtwo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

see code you we will get it

```
<html>

 <style>
body {
  background-image: url('background1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style> 


<style>
#mydiv,#mydiv1,#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader,#mydivheader1,#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Fun</h1>

<p>Click to move the card around</p>

<div id="mydiv" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div><br/>
<div id="mydiv1" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader1">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div><br/>
<div id="mydiv2" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader2">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>
```

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
//dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv,#mydiv1,#mydiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader,#mydivheader1,#mydivheader2 {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1>Fun</h1>

<p>Click to move the card around</p>

<div id="mydiv" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div><br/>
<div id="mydiv1" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader1">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div><br/>
<div id="mydiv2" onmousedown="dragElement(this)">
  <div id="mydivheader2">Click here</div>
  <p>This is a card with stuff on it.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
//dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

your all script no change</script>
```